# How to ensure all keys in object are strings?

Tags: typescript, object, generics, keyof

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt10QHgCqKoAeUqYAJgM6IDeA2gNaoCeAXIpVAE4xgDmAXXace-AL4A%20RAAo4AIwBWqaOzwAaREzaaWcYIjwBKWgChEKAIaU8cAEKoAyt159pWw2fNfv3gPS-EAD0AfhMxExMIBE5LaztHZ35EAF4ZADdhRL5jZKkaTy5UKBAuJDSwoA)

How do I get this key to be a string when it also has to be a keyof T?

```
function hello <T extends {[key: string]: string}> (object: T, key: keyof T) {
  hasToBeString(key)
              // ^?
}

const hasToBeString = (v: string) => {
  return v
}
```

[image]

Comment: ① Screenshots of IDEs are not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) (You should copy and paste any tooltip text into your plaintext) ② String index signatures do not *preclude* other key types, like `symbol` or `number`.  If you want to be sure that `key` is a `string` *and* a `keyof T`, you can give it the type `string & keyof T` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQ0VjW). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?